# omniauth_openid_connect gem - Authentication failure! invalid_request: Rack::OAuth2::Client::Error, invalid_request :: Client credentials are invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid-connect, omniauth

Im using this [gem](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth_openid_connect) to add Omniauth OpenID with a provider.

I configured the gem in the Devise Initializer, everything seems to be correct:

```
config.omniauth :openid_connect,
  {
      name: :openid_connect,
      scope: %i[openid profile groups_rewardops scope_rewardops],
      issuer: ConfigSettings.desjardins.issuer_url,
      response_type: :code,
      uid_field: 'sub',
      response_mode: :query,
      discovery: true,
      send_scope_to_token_endpoint: false,
      client_options:
      {
        port: 443,
        scheme: "https",
        host: ConfigSettings.desjardins.host,
        authorization_endpoint: "/affwebservices/CASSO/oidc/rewardops/authorize",
        token_endpoint: "/affwebservices/CASSO/oidc/rewardops/token",
        userinfo_endpoint: "/affwebservices/CASSO/oidc/rewardops/userinfo",
        identifier: ConfigSettings.desjardins.client_id,
        secret: ConfigSettings.desjardins.client_secret,
        redirect_uri: "#{ConfigSettings.api.base_url}front_end/users/auth/openid_connect/callback",
      },
  }
```

The flow I have atm is that the user can log in and grant access from the provider, then the provider sends a request to my devise callback url with the `nonce`, `code` and `state`. At this point everything seems to be correct but that request ends in `failure` when trying to generate the `access_token` with the following error:

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (openid_connect) Authentication failure! invalid_request: Rack::OAuth2::Client::Error, invalid_request :: Client credentials are invalid.
```

Im sure the `identifier` and the `secret` are correct, don't understand what's going on.

Since Im using `discovery` mode all the configs of the provider are in the `.well-known` you can check it [here](https://securefed-d.desjardins.com/affwebservices/CASSO/oidc/rewardops/.well-known/openid-configuration)

Im blocked without ideas about how to debug the error. Checking at `Rack::OAuth2` to see where the error is comming from I found [this](https://github.com/nov/rack-oauth2/blob/ced221f53aa6fd8abfd2232fd51527dd72ddfdfe/lib/rack/oauth2/server/resource/error.rb#L41) that says:

```
 invalid_request: "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter or parameter value, repeats the same parameter, uses more than one method for including an access token, or is otherwise malformed.",
```

It seems for some reason the access token request is malformed, but not sure what else apart of `identifier` and `secret` should I have in mind? I have seen many other examples of configuration and mine seems to be correct.

Comment: Can you post the rails server logs from the callback request failure?

Comment: @JasonS. just added full details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sure your credentials are correct, I suspect there is mismatch between the authentication method being used and the methods supported by the provider.  Checking the `.well-known` config, I see this provider only supports `client_secret_post`.  In your omniauth config, I see no options being passed to specify the authentication method.  When I dive down into the code, I see that the underlying oauth2 gem defaults to using `basic` auth, which uses the `indentifier` and `secret` to construct an `Authentication` header.  See: [source code here](https://github.com/nov/rack-oauth2/blob/master/lib/rack/oauth2/client.rb#L137)

```
client_auth_method = args.first || options.delete(:client_auth_method).try(:to_sym) || :basic

    case client_auth_method
    when :basic
      cred = Base64.strict_encode64 [
        Util.www_form_url_encode(identifier),
        Util.www_form_url_encode(secret)
      ].join(':')
      headers.merge!(
        'Authorization' => "Basic #{cred}"
      )
```

In the `client_secret_post` authentication method, instead of providing client secret in the header, the client authorizes itself providing the secret in the HTTP request body as a form parameter.  So this provider is not seeing your credentials. You could verify this by looking at the logs of the token endpoint request, which won't be visible in the browser, but rather from your rails BE to the the provider's server.

Try passing a `client_auth_method` in the `client_options` hash in your omniauth config. If you look at the case statement in the code I linked to above, there doesn't seem to be a named option for `client_secret_post`, but it is the default case. Any value for `client_auth_method` looks like it would work, but I would still use `client_secret_post`.

Comment: just a question, in the linked code you sent me they have this to set the `client_auth_method = args.first || options.delete(:client_auth_method).try(:to_sym) || :basic` it seems that it will always take the first argument but in the omniauth_openid_connect gem the first argument is `scope` when they call `access_token!` method

Comment: The `access_token!` method is defined as `def access_token!(*args)`.  `*args` are then passed along to `authenticated_context_from` (the code that I linked to).  In `authenticated_context_from`, the keyword arguments (which is how scope is passed) are extracted using `options = args.extract_options!`.   The net affect of all this is that args.first always maps to the first non-keyword argument.  The calling code is ONLY passing keyword arguments, so args.first will be `nil`